# Why chrome doesn't show my xml file processing result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, google-chrome

I'm making a web page using *JS* and *JQuery* with *HTML* and *CSS*, this webpage considered to extract some data from an **XML file** and display it as a **drpodown menu**, I'm using a JQuery library called [HeapBox](http://www.bartos.me/heapbox) as a customized dropdown menu.. every thing goes OK when dealing with **firefox**:

[image]

but when coming to **chrome** the *xml data* didn't shown:

[image]

```
$('#dummy').load('cafe.xml',function() { // dummy is a regular Div <div id="dummy> </div>
initialize();
})
function initialize(){
ct=$('menu').children().length;
for(var cati=0;cati<=ct-1;cati++)
{
cats[cati]=$('menu').children().eq(cati).prop('nodeName');
$('.basic-example').append('<option id="option1" value="option1">'+realname+'</option>');  //.basic-example is a heapbox integrated class 
}
$(".basic-example").heapbox({'onChange':function(){loadmenu()},effect:{type:"fade",speed:"slow"}});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

More interesting than the code here is the adressbar partially visible in the first screenshot. You are running this on local filesystem, but chrome doesn't allow AJAX on local filesystem.

Use a webserver to test your application.